# Error occurs as soon as the script run for more than 1 thread/user, it works flawlessly for 1 thread/user

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I recorded a complex scenario and correlated all the dynamic parameters.

I'm extracting a dynamic parameter i.e. Customer through Regular Expression Extractor. And passing it to subsequent requests.

The subsequent request(s) getting executed properly for 1st thread/user and failing for the other thread/user.

But error occurs as soon as the script run for more than 1 thread/user, it works flawlessly for 1 thread/user.

Why is it so, any ideas ?

Comment: If you won't provide detailed information about your problem, we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably didn't correlate some dynamic data which can be:

- In Header
- In Requests

Comment: Hi, I did correlate all dynamic data. If not, it should also fail for 1 (single) user. 

Also, I had created another script earlier where also same parameter is passed and it's working properly. Difference is just the scenario.

Comment: No because if you have the correct (recorded) data for 1 user, it may work for him. Try switching to another user and see what happens.